# Engrave text on image in c#

Tags: c#, image-manipulation, system.drawing

So I'll probably get scolded for asking such a broad question but it's worth a shot since google and stack overflow haven't really given me an answer.  I work for a funeral service company (depressing I know) and I am trying to figure out the best way to mimic engraving on an urn.  The engraving surface can be round or flat.  Has anyone ever done something similar in C#?  I can identify the engraveable area easy enough but figuring out the best way to make it curve with the object or size according to the available area is something I'm having trouble figuring out.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your 2 problems are obviously the embossed/engraved look, and the curvature, writing this your self maybe a steep learning curve, however there are probably image processing libraries that may have these sorts plugins, you will just need to keep looking

Comment: The embossed/engraved look I've got down.  I created the first version of this engraving tool a couple of years ago based on swatches of the actual product.  Following the curvature though, you're right, this is the main problem.  I don't mind research and learning, I'm just not sure of the best place to start.  Thanks for the comment @TheGeneral!

Comment: You're best bet is probably texture mapping to a 3d mesh. Your engraved text will be the texture and you would need to construct a 3d mesh to mimic the curvature of the urn. I haven't played enough with that to show you how to do it. But it's a very common thing in game development. There should be plenty of resources/tutorials available. Depending on the requirements of your final solution, you may even be able to use something like Unity to cheat a little.

Comment: Thank you Nigel! It was basically those keyword I was looking for. Appreciate the comment!

Comment: Edge detection algorithms like [Sobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) can also give an embossed look.